# How to pass session object with JSON response in php?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, session

Before giving detail information on Question, I want to tell that architecture of project, project is design in three separate parts
**1.** UI Part, this is in **Pure HTM-5,** JavaScript, Ajax, JSON, RestFull API, there is **no any embedded code like PHP, jSP**.
**2.** Service Part, service is written in PHP, URL of these services access by UI part.
**3.** DataBase
 **I don't want to add any PHP code in HTML file**

Now I want to create login form in pure html page, After successfully login it redirect to userProfile, Now user able to update the profile, I want to main session for this type scenario. 
I am successfully able to login and redirect to userProfile with info Which I fetch from server using JSON, and send this info to userProfile with help of storeUserDataInSession. **Now I want to add Update and Logout facility without send again userName and password**, please help me on this, I am new in session management.

**JavaScript for Login form**

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function(){

                var userData = {
                 storeUserDataInSession: function(userData) {
                     var userObjectString = JSON.stringify(userData);
                     window.sessionStorage.setItem('userObject',userObjectString)
                 },
                 getUserDataFromSession: function() {
                     var userData = window.sessionStorage.getItem('userObject')
                     return JSON.parse(userData);
                 }
                }   

               $("#register-form-header").submit(function(){            

                var uName = $('#userName').val();               
                var upassd=$('#password').val();    
                $.ajax({                                        
                    url:"http://localhost/login/login.php",                     
                    type:"POST",
                    dataType:"json",
                    data:{type:"login",uName:uName,password:upassd},                    

                    ContentType:"application/json",
                    success: function(response){

                        userData.storeUserDataInSession(response);

                        window.location = 'userProfile.html';

                    },
                    error: function(err){                           
                        //alert(JSON.stringify(err));
                        alert("fail");
                        window.location.href = 'error.html';
                    }           
                });
                return false; 

        });
        //loadJSON(0);
    });
</script>
```

**JavaScript for UserProfile**

```
<script>             
  $( document ).ready(function() {
       var userData = {
         storeUserDataInSession: function(userData) {
             var userObjectString = JSON.stringify(userData);
             window.sessionStorage.setItem('userObject',userObjectString)
         },
         getUserDataFromSession: function() {
             var userData = window.sessionStorage.getItem('userObject')
             return JSON.parse(userData);
         }
        } 

        var userDataObject=userData.getUserDataFromSession();
        var id =userDataObject[0].userInfo.id;
        var username =userDataObject[0].userInfo.username;
        var name =userDataObject[0].userInfo.name;
        var address =userDataObject[0].userInfo.address;
        var mobile =userDataObject[0].userInfo.mobile;
        var email =userDataObject[0].userInfo.email;            
        document.getElementById('welcomeUser').innerHTML="Welcome Mr"+username;
        document.getElementById('userName').value=username;
        document.getElementById('Name').value=name;
        document.getElementById('email').value=email;
        document.getElementById('mobile').value=mobile;
        document.getElementById('address1').value=address;


  }); 
</script>
```

**Login service in php**

```
<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');//Should work in Cross Domaim ajax Calling request
    include("config.php");
    //session_start();
    if(isset($_POST['type']))
    {
        if($_POST['type']=="login"){
            $name = $_POST ['uName'];             
            $password=$_POST ['password'];
            $query="SELECT id, username, address, name, mobile, email FROM admin WHERE UserName='nee' AND PASSWORD='12'";           
            $result=mysql_query($query);
            $totalRows=mysql_num_rows($result); 
            if($totalRows>0){
                $recipes=array();
                while($recipe=mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
                    $recipes[]=array('userInfo'=>$recipe);
                }
                echo json_encode($recipes);         
            }   
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "Invalid format";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using cookies for this. And don't return user profile information on login API response, instead create another API in PHP something like ~/user/{userId}/profile.

On the login PHP code, use setcookie() function to set the session id in the client browser cookie. The login API should just return 200 OK on successful authentication. In case of login failure, it should return 401 Forbidden.

On the JavaScript login page, when you receive 200 OK Status code, redirect the page to Profiles page. On the profiles page, call ~/user/{userId}/profile API to get user information and display it.

In profile API PHP Code, make sure you validate the session id in the cookie field $_COOKIE. if the session id is not valid, return 401 Forbidden error.

On the logout PHP API, remove the session id from the cookie field.

With this approach, you send username and password details only once when calling login API. After that, you rely on session id stored in cookie field for authentication.

For more information, read this http://www.pontikis.net/blog/create-cookies-php-javascript

Comment: thanks for Reply, I don't want to add any PHP code in HTML file

Comment: No, you will not be adding any PHP code in the HTML file. I never said that. You will only be writing REST style APIs in PHP that return JSON response for JavaScript consumption on the browser side

Comment: I have one question to you, I discuses architecture of project, Is this right approach and secure, If any suggestion please tell me..

Comment: Your approach is not a good architecture and will break easily. I would highly suggest you to write REST APIs in PHP (http://coreymaynard.com/blog/creating-a-restful-api-with-php/) and consume the response in pure HTML5 JavaScript applicaiton

Answer (score 0):

Any server language (PHP / JSP) etc uses session-variables (upon request) that you probably want to store on your side (JS/HTML). Communicating with logout or update services is then done with this session-variable-value as an argument.

You'd probably store the variable as a cookie or using localStorage.

in cleartext, the login should return JSON

```
username: name,
session-id: 2352-2532-2352-235-235
```